# Powershell: Convert Table Row To String Values

Tags: sql-server, powershell

In a Powershell script I have the following code. I am trying to enumerate a list of DB tables from SQL and then use that list to execute subsequent commands.

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases 
      WHERE name NOT IN ('tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')"

$ListOfDatabases = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $s.ServerName 
                                 -Username $s.Username 
                                 -Password $s.Pass 
                                 -Query $q 

foreach ($db in $ListOfDatabases) {

         #If I just print $db Like so...
             $db
         # yields 
         #       name
         #       -------
         #       table1
         #       table2

         #But If I Try to use that value I get an error
             $Q = "EXECUTE SOME_PROC($db)"
             $Q   
         #   yields 
         #    EXECUTE SOME_PROC([System.Data.DataRow])
         #    EXECUTE SOME_PROC([System.Data.DataRow])
         #    EXECUTE SOME_PROC([System.Data.DataRow])
         #     etc... for each table
```

So where am I going wrong here? I'm trying to extract the string value table1 and table 2, etc for all the tables and use it in another SQL command. And because the SO editor is yelling at me telling me that my post is mostly code, I am adding this additional sentence to help 'convince' it to let me submit this question. -Given that most of my "explaining" is done in the comments of the code.

Comment: Why don't you use `EXECUTE SOME_PROC($(db.name))"`? It says right there that the property is called "name". ;)

Comment: It would have to be `$Q = "EXECUTE SOME_PROC($($db.Name))"` if you were to try that. Accessing Properties inside a string needs to be done in a subexpression.

Comment: @Frode F. Thank you even more :)

Comment: Do either of you want credit? Post an answer.. I'll mark it solved

Comment: @FrodeF. Go ahead. I'm off for today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`$db` is a datarow-object with a `name` property. Try a subexpression to extract the value of the name-property:

```
$Q = "EXECUTE SOME_PROC($($db.Name))"
```

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is expand the variable to get just the name instead of an object with a name property and call the stored proc with only the value.

```
$q = "SELECT name FROM master..sysdatabases 
      WHERE name NOT IN ('tempdb', 'model', 'msdb')"

$ListOfDatabases = Invoke-Sqlcmd -ServerInstance $s.ServerName 
                                 -Username $s.Username 
                                 -Password $s.Pass 
                                 -Query $q 

foreach ($db in $ListOfDatabases) {

    #If I just print $db Like so...
    #    $db
    # yields 
    #       name
    #       -------
    #       table1
    #       table2

    # So we need to delve into each name separately like so
    ForEach ($dbName in $db.Name)
    {
        # This will call the proc with each name in $db
        $Q = "EXECUTE SOME_PROC($dbName)"
        $Q   
    }
}
```